# UITapGestureRecognizer does not apply on UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

May be it has been answered before but, I was unable to find it.
I am creating random `UIImageView` instances and adding them as subViews to the view of a `viewController`.

In the same way I am creating `UITapGestureRecognizer` instances and adding them to the `UIImageView` instances.
But the Tap doesn't work.

```
for _ in 0..<20 {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: randomXGenerator(), y: randomYGenerator())
        iv.frame.size.width = randomGenerator()
        iv.frame.size.height = iv.frame.width
        iv.tintColor = UIColor.random() //To color the image inside the imageView
        iv.image = bubble
        view.addSubview(iv)
        animateBubblesRandom(bubble: iv)
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedOnBubble(object:)))
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

And here are the instances of *TapGesture* created:

```
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012b5b00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e507660>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bed00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e70b0b0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf000; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e6041f0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf100; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e605fa0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf200; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e6079c0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf300; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e607d20>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf500; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e608080>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf600; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e6083e0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf700; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e414520>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012b5f00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e414750>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012b6000; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e70b2e0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bef00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e608b40>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bee00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e608ea0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf800; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e609200>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf900; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e6096b0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bfa00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e609a10>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bfb00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e609d70>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bfc00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e60a0d0>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bf400; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e60a630>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x6000012bfd00; state = Possible; view = <UIImageView 0x7fdf4e60a990>; target= <(action=tappedOnBubbleWithObject:, target=<FloatingBubbles.ViewController 0x7fdf4e605440>)>>
```

I do not understand why this is happening. Please help!

Comment: What does `But the Tap doesn't work.` mean?

Comment: The action for the `tap` doesn't fire at all. But surprisingly it fires if the tap is applied on the `view` of the `viewController`.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is `tappedOnBubble` never gets called?

Comment: Yes, for the UIImageView instances.

Comment: Comment this line `animateBubblesRandom(bubble: iv)` and check what happens.
`

Comment: It does fire. @Kamran So, the `animateBubblesRandombubble:` has to do something with it. Then, how do I apply the animation and tap gesture at the same time?

Comment: Show us animateBubblesRandom. Maybe you forgot to ask for touchability. By default an animated view is not touchable. Plus, a moving animated view cannot be touched without hit test munging.

Comment: You can try this `UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {` for animation. But it would be better if you can include the `animateBubblesRandombubble` method in your question.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to set the recognizer before you call the animation... in addition to other answers/comments.

Comment: @matt 

`@objc func animateBubblesRandom(bubble: UIImageView) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: randomTimeIntervalGenerator(), animations: {
            bubble.frame = CGRect(x: randomXGenerator(), y: randomYGenerator(), width: bubble.frame.width, height: bubble.frame.height)
        }) { _ in
            self.animateBubblesRandom(bubble: bubble)
        }
    }`

Comment: @matt I didn't ask for touchabiliy. :(

Comment: **Karman** and **Boober Bunz** I gotta try these out. I'll let you know what happens. :) Thanks for helping

Comment: Well my answer explains how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A UIImageView cannot be touched unless you set its `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true.
- An animated view cannot be touched unless you use the `.allowUserInteraction` animation option.

Plus you must subclass and implement special hit testing (because an animated view may not actually be located at the place the user sees it and tries to click):

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let pres = self.layer.presentation()!
    let suppt = self.convert(point, to: self.superview!)
    let prespt = self.superview!.layer.convert(suppt, to: pres)
    return super.hitTest(prespt, with: e)
}
```

Comment: See my explanation starting at http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_hit_testing_during_animation